# Having (not P or Q) true, and (P and Q) => R true, show that P=>R

Tags: logic

So far I think its something like this:

(P and R) => R

~(P and R) or R:      De Morgan's

[(~P or ~Q) or R] and [~P or Q]: Addition

~P or [Q and (~Q or R)]

And here I'm stuck. I feel like theres something to do with resolution. Any step I messed up?

Comment: Using proper math formatting would be great for better readability

Comment: https://www.umsu.de/trees/#((~3P~0~2~0~0Q)~0~1~0((P~1~0Q)~5R))~5(P~5R)

Comment: You could do a simple table as well

Comment: "there's something to do with resolution" ? Maybe you **have to use** Resolution...

Comment: What rules do you have?

Comment: If you want to apply Resolution, rewrite the formula as clauses: $\lnot P \lor Q$ and $\lnot P \lor \lnot Q \lor R$ and add the negation of the conclusion. The apply [Resolution proof procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)#Resolution_in_propositional_logic).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what rules of inference are available to you, but the proof should go something like this:  If $P$ is true, then because we know $\lnot P \lor Q$, we also know that $Q$ is true.  But if we know that both $P$ and $Q$ are true, then $(P \land Q) \Rightarrow R$ tells us that $R$ is true.  Putting this together, if $P$ is true, we know that $R$ also must be true, so we have $P \Rightarrow R$.